# Print integer dictionary in order in Julia

Tags: dictionary, printing, julia

Suppose I have a dictionary, let's call it myDict, where the keys are the natural numbers 1, 2, ..., n.
When I code

```
println(myDict)
```

it doesn't necessarily print the dictionary "in order". For example, if I code

```
myDict = Dict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0)
```

and then write `println(myDict)`, the following output is displayed:

```
Dict{Any,Any}(4 => 0,2 => 0.9,3 => 0.8,5 => 0,1 => 0.9)
```

but I would like the output to be displayed like:

```
Dict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0).
```

I don't want to do a for-loop and find the lowest key and then print that etc. I want the output to really be just like `Dict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0)`. Is there an argument/parameter I can pass into the `println()` command, or something like that, to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `OrderedDict` from [`DataStructures`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl) package. For performance reasons, order is not defined on ordinary dictionaries.

Comment: Or [`Dictionaries.jl`](https://github.com/andyferris/Dictionaries.jl).

Answer (score 3):

`Dict`s do not have a specific key order. Moreover the key order it not guaranteed to be stable throughout execution.

Hence most likely what you are looking for is an `OrderedDict`:

```
julia> using DataStructures

julia> myDict = OrderedDict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0)
OrderedDict{Any, Any} with 5 entries:
  1 => 0.9
  2 => 0.9
  3 => 0.8
  4 => 0
  5 => 0

julia> println(myDict)
OrderedDict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0)
```

Another thing you might consider is to override the `Base.show` method for `Dict` or `AbstractDict`:

```
function Base.show(io::IO, d::Dict)
   for key in sort!(collect(keys(d)))
       println(io, " $key => $(d[key])")
   end
end
```

And now you get:

```
julia> println(Dict{Any, Any}(1 => 0.9, 2 => 0.9, 3 => 0.8, 4 => 0, 5 => 0))
 1 => 0.9
 2 => 0.9
 3 => 0.8
 4 => 0
 5 => 0
```

Comment: I know @Przemyslaw knows this, but to others: do *not* override the `show` method in package code (that's piracy). But you can do it locally if needed.